# Two while loops, Python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I wanna have a code that finds all "i"s in a string and returns the number of occurrence of it and the position of the character. But will get [this forever loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qxxN.jpg) and I do not know why.

```
code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
i=code_tip.count("i")
length=len(code_tip)
n=0
y=0

while n < i:
    while y <length:
            y = code_tip.find("i", y, -1)
            print(n, ":", y)
            y+=1
            n+=1

while n < i:
    if y <length:
            y = code_tip.find("i", y, -1)
            print(n, ":", y)
            y+=1
            n+=1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You reset your loop variable regularly: ``y = code_tip.find("i", y, -1)`` sets ``y`` to -1 when it cannot find the character. That will always be the case if i is not the last character in the string you search through.

Comment: You don't have an exit clause. Y never gets past the last location

Comment: `import re; [i.start() for i in re.finditer("i",code_tip)]` this should be able to give you all the positions of i in your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @scrappedcola mentioned, you are missing the exit clause.

```
code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
i=code_tip.count("i")
length=len(code_tip)
n=0
y=0

while n < i:
    while y <length:
            y = code_tip.find("i", y, -1)
            print(n, ":", y)
            y+=1
            n+=1
            if y==0:
                break

print('entering second loop')
while n < i:
    if y <length:
            y = code_tip.find("i", y, -1)
            print(n, ":", y)
            y+=1
            n+=1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: ``y`` is -1 (not 0), if ``"i"`` is not found.

Comment: there is a y+=1 before the if clause. I tested this code and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
i=code_tip.count("i")

y = 0
k = {}
for i in range(i): 
    s = code_tip.find("i",y)
    k[i] = s
    y = s + 1

{0: 11, 1: 13, 2: 22, 3: 24, 4: 29, 5: 47}
```

Of course you can decide to print instead of saving it in a dictionary.
This can also be done as:

```
import re
[i.start() for i in re.finditer("i",code_tip)]
[11, 13, 22, 24, 29, 47]
```